# Amplify @model syntax to only generate create and update mutations (not delete)

Tags: aws-amplify

I'm working on GraphQL schema using Amplify.  I only want to generate 'create' and 'update' mutations (not delete).  What is the syntax or process to accomplish this?

I have tried things like this but no luck.

```
type Post @model(mutations: {create, update}) {
     id: ID!
     title: String!
     tags: [String!]!
 }
```